# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier how to avoid it

Tags: ios, uitableview

i'm using table view to display loaded array of textfields from server ,so i have a table view list of fields , when i fill this fields of data and scroll down to fill other fields when i scroll up again i found the values changes and there is a duplicated valus

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FieldCell";
        //FieldCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    FieldCell *cell = [[FieldCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //Filling The DataHere
    cell.cellImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.cellTextField.placeholder = [placeHolders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;

}
```

i think the problem in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier because it re allocate and allocate the cell , but i don't want to do this i want to let every thing in memory with its values

Comment: Can you show your entire `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method? You can't avoid cell reuse - it is a fundamental part of the technique used to display tables while minimising memory use, but it is used successfully in literally hundreds of thousands of apps, so you have an issue somewhere else in your code.

Comment: i think the problem that , every cell has a text field , lets assume its from 1 - 100 ,, when i write in the list  [one  - two .... hunderd] , when i scroll back i find that cell one has for example seven ,, i think the problem that he remove the cell from the memory and when he reallocate it again it come with wrong values , there is nothing more in my code i just wanna do this

Comment: If the first cell is showing the wrong value when you scroll back, then the problem is definitely not `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, but rather your broader `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and we cannot help you fix it if you don't share it with us.

Comment: how could the problem is cellForRowAtIndexPath ?? its just a number ,, i want you to notice that the cells don't display the data from array or something ,, every thing is on memory ,, what the user write in textfields not stored in any thing ,, i was intend to loop on the table and access cell and then get what the user wrote

Comment: and this is my function

Comment: @mohamed: Don't you want to reuse tableViewCell, If not needed use static tableView.

Comment: what do you mean by static tableView what i should change in my structure to make it static ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is responsible for obtaining a cell and putting the right value into it - this is why I asked you to show the entire method.  The code you have put in your question is not a complete `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

**Update** - I have included a simple delegate call back from the cell to the tableview to allow the UITextField delegate in the cell to update the backing store.  I didn't use a proper protocol for the delegate because I wanted to throw this together quickly.

FieldCell.h

```
@class TableView

@property (strong,nonatomic) TableView *delegate;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSIndexPath indexPath;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UITextField *textField;
```

FieldCell.c

```
#import <TableView.h>

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITextFieldDelegate

- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (self.delegate)
    {
        [self.delegate updateCellText:[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] forIndexPath:self.indexPath;

    }
    return YES;
}
```

TableView.h

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cellTexts;       //  You need to initialise this as an array full of empty NSStrings or whatever the initial cell values should be

- (void) updateCellText:(NSString *)text forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath;
```

TableView.c

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FieldCell";
        FieldCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.indexPath=indexPath;
        cell.delegate=self;
        cell.textField.text=[self.cellTexts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    // modify this as required to actually put your data to be displayed into the cell's properties

        return cell;
    }

- (void) updateCellText:(NSString *)text forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath
{

  [self.cellTexts replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:text];
}
```

Comment: the problem is that , i don't have array to load this ,, i just have textfields ,, set the place holder here ,, but the content of textfield come from user , so i couldn't load it

Comment: i need the user write what he want then i loop to get it from him ,, but the prom on scroll up and down , the value of text field changed

Comment: You still need a backing store (array) to hold the contents of the cells - A tableview is just that - a view onto your data.  It doesn't hold your data. In this case you will need an array of NSStrings and you need to have the event handler for the cell's text field  update the appropriate element in the array. Since you have a custom cell you can store the IndexPath as a property of the cell and have the UITextField delegate for the cell be the FieldCell. When the value changes you can use a delegate pattern to call a method in your tableview controller with the new value and the indexPath

Comment: i understand your solution but its too long , is there is work around to solve this ? ,,  i though about this but i felt that there is an easier way

Comment: The right way is also the easy way. I will update my answer to show how it can be done.

Comment: thanks i already finished it ,, this is the only way to work :)

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you can accept my answer it would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question

**dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier how to avoid it ?**

```
FieldCell *cell = [[FieldCell alloc]init];
```

This will allocate memory to each cell and will not reuse them but...

By all means , please please **don't do this**, it will give you a poor performance memory wise, you will even notice a lag when scrolling the table.

The **real** solution to your problem is not to rely on the cell content since they are being reused, instead you should manage to store the `UITextfield` value in your model as you input them.

Comment: Absolutely 100% agree. The solution is to set up the model and use it properly. Not to try and break the tableview.

Comment: thanks for reply :) , first how to give cell identifier if i use this way  ? and there is no problem in performance because in my case this in registration its only one time and there is no fields more than 10

Comment: i tried this     FieldCell *cell = [[FieldCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 but i received memory warning and the table view cells don't appear

Comment: i tried your answer but the cell don't appear , i think because it needs to take the identifier